# use arrow functions with two values e.g. Array.sort Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I know how to use an arrow function for e.g. Array.filter() method, as you only need one value: `var a = array.filter(val=>{return val<=5;});`
but how do you do it with more than one value like with sort? I tried this but it doesn't work:`array.sort(a,b)=>{return b-a;});`

Comment: You're missing an opening parenthesis on your `sort` call.

Comment: Please refer [MDN - Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use right parenthesis for the arguments.

```
array.sort((a, b) => b - a);
//         ^    ^
```